# Unable to share to Tiktok using Tiktok Video kit sdk Android

Tags: android, video, sdk, tiktok

I am currently having an issue where I am unable to share to Tiktok using their video kit sdk, I am using the FileProvider implementation (I have tried the other implementation but I get the same error) https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/video-kit-android-android-fileprovider

Currently, when press to share to Tiktok I get this error:

```
Instrumentation: Uninitialized ActivityThread, likely app-created Instrumentation, disabling AppComponentFactory
java.lang.Throwable
    at android.app.Instrumentation.getFactory(Instrumentation.java:1228)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3015)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

The app Intents to Tiktok and shows the Tiktok app opening but this just crashes with the above error?

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: Please make sure you are passing correct path, also if you know error code it's better. In my case, I was passing wrong path, that cause error 20010, which is ''Processing photo resources failed.''

https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/getting-started-android-handling-errors/